How do I scroll through and print result from a website using selenium. I’m trying to scrape a website but It’s not printing all the results
I'm scaping booking.com with selenium, it has over 600 results, but selenium is scaping only 51 results. I do not know what I am doing wrong. This is my code.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=397645&label=bin859jc-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaKcBiAEBmAExuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAK-xqeyBsACAdICJGEwYTAzM2QwLTQ1MjEtNGIzNi04NTYyLTcxMjY5NzJlMGNjNtgCBOACAQ&sid=968beab70293559758c39b5f6e59b26e&checkin=2024-05-20&checkout=2024-05-23&region=5140&'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

name = []
location = []

container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "d4924c9e74")
apartment = container.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@role, "group")]')

for x in apartment:
    name.append(x.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[contains(@data-testid, "title")]').text)
    location.append(x.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@data-testid, "address")]').text)
    # print(x.text)

hotels = {
    'name' : name,
    'location' : location
}
print(hotels)

This is my result
{'name': ['The Mora Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Zanziblue\nOpens in new window', 'Maisha Nungwi\nOpens in new window', 'Baladin Zanzibar Beach Hotel\nOpens in new window', 'Be Zanzibar Boutique Hotel\nOpens in new window', 'Promised Land Lodge\nOpens in new window', 'Kwanza Resort by SUNRISE\nOpens in new window', 'Karafuu Beach Resort & Spa\nOpens in new window', 'Hekaya Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Paradise Beach Resort & Spa\nOpens in new window', 'Zuri Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Tembo House Hotel\nOpens in new window', 'Sunset Kendwa Beach Hotel\nOpens in new window', 'Villa Nyota Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Kizikula\nOpens in new window', 'Hotel Riu Jambo - All Inclusive\nOpens in new window', 'Chumbe Island Coral Park\nOpens in new window', 'Gold Zanzibar Beach House & Spa\nOpens in new window', 'Mtende Beach Bungalow océan view\nOpens in new window', 'Le Mersenne Zanzibar, Autograph Collection\nOpens in new window', 'Pongwe Bay Resort\nOpens in new window', 'Aurelia Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Aya Beach Resort\nOpens in new window', 'Z-Lodge Zanzibar\nOpens in new window', 'Mayai Ocean Resort\nOpens in new window'], 'location': ['Matemwe', 'Matemwe', 'Nungwi Beach, Nungwi', 'Michamvi', 'Mfumbwi', 'Kizimkazi Beach, Kizimkazi', 'Kizimkazi', 'Pingwe', 'Pingwe', 'Uroa', 'Kendwa Beach, Kendwa', 'Zanzibar City', 'Kendwa Beach, Kendwa', 'Kidenga', 'Kizimkazi', 'Nungwi', 'Mbweni', 'Kendwa Beach, Kendwa', 'Mtende', 'Michamvi', 'Pongwe', 'Ngambo', 'Kizimkazi Beach, Kizimkazi', 'Kiwengwa', 'Bwejuu Beach, Bwejuu']}


the results load dynamically as you scroll. You need to use selenium to scroll down the page to load all the results.
See here for example
